Security of modified CBC$ mode encryption
I am trying to understand the (IND-CPA or lack thereof) security of a modified CBC mode. Instead of choosing the IV completely at random per plaintext, the adversary provides a "pre-IV" value, that along with a per-plaintext secret random value, is run through the underlying block cipher to generate the actual IV. Encryption proceeds as usual using CBC mode with the IV.
Let $\mathcal{E} = (\text{Enc}, \text{Dec})$ be an encryption scheme over keyspace $\mathcal{K} = \{0,1\}^{128}$, IV space $\{0,1\}^{128}$, message space $\mathcal{M} = \{0,1\}^{128l}$, and ciphertext space $\mathcal{C} = \{0,1\}^{128(l+1)}$. Assume $\mathcal{E}$ is implemented using some underlying block cipher $f : \mathcal{K} \times \{0,1\}^{128} \xrightarrow{} \{0,1\}^{128}$ in CBC mode, e.g. AES128-CBC. When used with a random IV, $\mathcal{E}$ is IND-CPA secure. Define a modified encryption scheme $\mathcal{E}' = (\text{Enc}', \text{Dec}')$ over IV space $\{0,1\}^{64}$.
$\text{Enc}'(k,piv,m) = r \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} \{0,1\}^{64}, iv \xleftarrow{} f(k,piv \vert\vert r), c \xleftarrow{} \text{Enc}(k, iv, m); \text{return } (iv, c)$
My intuition tells me that, assuming $f$ is secure block cipher, and thus the CBC mode encryption scheme using $f$ with a random IV is IND-CPA secure, then the modified $\mathcal{E}'$ encryption scheme is also secure (up to some security loss). This is because the IV in the modified scheme is indistinguishable, up to some security loss, from the random IV in CBC mode. However, I am having some trouble proving it. Any assistance would be great.
Attempt
To show the modified CBC scheme is IND-CPA secure, I argue that it is indistinguishable (under CPA) from regular CBC encryption with a random IV. The hybrids are:

H0: $k \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} k, \text{Oracle0}(piv,m) := iv \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} \{0,1\}^{128}, c \xleftarrow{} \text{Enc}(k,iv,m); \text{return } (iv, c)$
H1: $k \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} k, F \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} \text{Funcs}[\{0,1\}^{128},\\{0,1\\}^{128}], \text{Oracle1}(piv,m) := r \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} \{0,1\}^{64}, iv \xleftarrow{} F(piv \vert\vert r), c \xleftarrow{} \text{Enc}(k,iv,m); \text{return } (iv, c)$
H2: $k \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} k, \text{Oracle2}(piv,m) := r \stackrel{\\\$}{\gets} \{0,1\}^{64}, iv \xleftarrow{} f(k, piv \vert\vert r), c \xleftarrow{} \text{Enc}(k,iv,m); \text{return } (iv, c)$

The indistinguishability of H1 and H2 follows from the fact that $f$ is a PRF, so it remains to show the indistinguishability of H0 and H1. I was thinking of using a statistical distance argument, but I'm having difficulty finding closed forms or bounds for the terms. Any help would be appreciated! If there's a better proof, I'm also all ears.

"Any assistance would be great" - hint - what happens if the attacker asks for the encryption of $2^{32}$ identical messages?

Just identical messages but unique "pre-IVs", I believe the result should be indistinguishable from CBC mode with 128-bit random IV (by $f$ being a PRF). If the 64-bit pre-IVs are all the same, then a full IV collision should occur w.h.p. after about $2^{32}$ encryption queries (compared to $2^{64}$ queries with a random 128-bit IV). Is this what you are getting at?

Showing that H1 $\approx$ H2 is not as easy as you make it sound. You want to apply the security of the PRF, but the PRF key is also being used inside of Enc.

H0: $k \stackrel{$}{\gets} \mathcal{K}, \text{Oracle0}(piv,m) := iv \stackrel{$}{\gets} {0,1}^{128}, (iv,c) \gets \text{Enc}(k,iv,m)$ (This is more cleaner) H0: $k \stackrel{\$}{\gets} \mathcal{K}, \text{Oracle0}(piv,m) := iv \stackrel{\$}{\gets} \{0,1\}^{128}, (iv,c) \gets \text{Enc}(k,iv,m)$
